# Subquery in SearchCursor with ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I'm searching for the value from the field "demA_demA" which has the lowest elevation by having the value 8 from the field "outTable_2".

[image]

How can I do this in the following script.

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.overwriteOutput = True

env.workspace = r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\testdatenC"

inASCII = r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\testdatenC\2007040_cloud_free.asc"
outRaster = inASCII + "_out.img"
rasterType = "INTEGER"
# Process: ASCII in Raster
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(inASCII, outRaster, rasterType)
# Process: Projektion definieren
   arcpy.DefineProjection_management(outRaster,"GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHER OID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
# Process: Sample
outTable = r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\ergebnisse3\outTable.dbf"
Sample(outRaster, outRaster, outTable, "NEAREST")
#works
# Join the table
# Table view
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\ergebnisse\outTable.dbf",     "out_tview") #works

joinField = "Y"
joinTable = r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\ergebnisse3\demA.dbf"
arcpy.AddJoin_management("out_tview", joinField, joinTable, joinField, "KEEP_ALL")
# Persist the layer on disk
arcpy.CopyRows_management("out_tview",     r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\ergebnisse3\joinTestC.dbf")
# Execute CreateFileGDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\result", "test1.gdb")     #works
outLocation = r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\result\test.gdb"
# Execute TableToTable
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\ergebnisse3\joinTestC.dbf",     outLocation, "jointest1") #works
# search for the lowest elevation with the value 8
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\result\test1.gdb\jointest1",     ["outTable_2", "demA_demA"], """""demA_demA" = min("demA_demA")AND "outTable_2" = 8""") as     cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row [0], row [1]
```

Do I have to add the geodatabase because of an subquery? How should I write the subquery? I'm pretty new and working with ArcMap 10.2.1

Comment: I suspect that this question amounts to a (near) duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70488/subquery-a-list-in-select-layer-by-attribute-management-using-python but in any event as @Hornbydd says the way to achieve this is by using the Summary Statistics tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using your screenshot for an example you are searching for the minimum value in demA-demA where outtable_2 = 8, so in this example it would 3356?

If this is correct then this is simply the [summary statistics tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/). Your CASE field would be outtable_2 and you are returning the minimum value from demA_demA

Comment: Perfect, that is much better than what I thought! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So I added this:                                   ``    arcpy.CopyRows_management("out_tview", r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\testdE\ergebnisE\joinXYZB7.dbf") #works

arcpy.Statistics_analysis (r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\testdE\ergebnisE\joinXYZB7.dbf", "D:\Julia_T\projekt\aufgabe2\testdE\ergebnisE\statistic1.dbf", [["dem500_dem", "MIN"], ["outTable1_", "MAX"]], "outTable1_")`` But I get the ERORR 000210 and don't know way.

Comment: put an **r** in front of the path name for your output table like you have done for your input table.